# Better way to write this jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, selector

what would be a better way to write this jQuery selector:

```
// this is called when .nextButton is invoked.
$(this).parent('.question').children('.options').children('.options > li').children('.selected').parent('li').attr('id'));
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="question" id="question1">
      <p>What is your age:</p>
      <ul class="options question1Options">
        <li id="q1-1"><div class="radio"></div>10-20.</li>
        <li id="q1-2"><div class="radio"></div>21-30.</li>
        <li id="q1-3"><div class="radio"></div>31-40.</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="nextButton"></div>
    </div>
```

When a user clicks on one of these li's it will add a class selected (like a radio button, only one is selected). I'm trying to get the id of the selected radio/li. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(this).closest('div.question').find('.radio.selected').closest('li').attr('id');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Eee6t/2/)

Comment: I'm accepting this because it makes better sense than what @Sushil suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Reduced code:

```
$(this).siblings('.options').find('.selected').parent('li').attr('id');
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm seeing something wrong, but this won't work

Comment: why, It should, as .options has same parent as this.

Comment: @Sushil I was seeing something wrong, I though you were searching for "question" in `.siblings('.options')`, my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intentions correctly:

```
$('.radio').on('click',function(e) {
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/edKM6/